# OpenCV - best approach to detect multiple similar, but different objects

Tags: image-processing, opencv

My objective is to find multiple barcodes from the pictures with OpenCV. I have tried using SURF to find them, but the method is ineffective in that case (features not unique enough). I was also considering HAAR, but it is not a rotation invariant method.

What do you think is the best approach to handle this problem?

([Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGdxr.jpg))

[image]

Comment: what is this image actually? Never seen like this before.

Comment: Sample tubes with unique identifier.

Comment: These objects are all the same to me: circles with something on them. Are you already able to extract the circles that matters ?

Comment: Suppose you have the approximate region of each barcode as in http://i.imgur.com/XOw2y.png. What else do you wanna do ?

Comment: Are these data matrix codes? If so, do you want to decode them? If so, have you tried http://www.libdmtx.org ?

Comment: @mmgp The image you made is great. Is it sth more than threshold? How did you achieved it?

Comment: @Dobi For now I just want to find the areas with codes.

Comment: Are you saying you want to just detect if a tube is present or not? or that you want to find the actual rotated square containing the barcode?

Comment: If you could find the white separator bars reliably, you could at least infer the barcode center locations.

Comment: @Jacek: In Matlab `f = rgb2gray(imread('http://i.stack.imgur.com/4XBbu.jpg')); g = bwareaopen(bwmorph(edge(f - imopen(f, strel('disk', 3)), 'sobel'), 'dilate'), 150);`. Then `g` is the image in the earlier link.

Answer (score 1):

Train a Support Vector Machine. Create a dataset with many barcodes in many orientations. When testing an image, build a scale-pyramid and apply a sliding window technique. It's called "Object detection". Also "multiple similar but different" is called intra-class variation.

Edit: Or try [this](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~gallju/projects/houghforest/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. I will do some research on SVM.

Comment: This is also referred to "I have no idea how to properly handle the problem, so I will just let this magic black-box attempt to solve it". Yes, I'm not particularly fond of using machine learning except if there is a really good reason to.

Comment: @mmgp object detection/classification uses machine learning. Check state of the art libraries.

Comment: @BillyL By "state of the art libraries" do you mean the latest version of some library ? State of the art refers to the current research development in the field, so that is weird expression at least. I've seen quite a few papers on it, most of them bad, some very good. Most of the bad ones are those where the person describing the work assumes that he has such a big dataset, that barely pre-processing its inputs is likely to produce good results nevertheless, so he proceeds to extract features as "usual". Now, see, "build a scale-pyramid", "apply a sliding window technique" are way too vague.

Comment: (continuing) Those techniques have many many ways to be performed, do you mean to use all them that you know ? Finally, you mention SVM in general, but that has no chance to work against only a positive class dataset. If you want to follow on that, One-Class SVM is likely to be more appropriate. But, the need for machine learning hasn't been stablished yet (only your answer has, I don't see how that is enough).

Comment: @mmgp well, first of all this forum is mainly technical. This post is not. It's theoretical. So I just gave a directional answer, not a real one. Check SoA in the literature (e.g. IEEE Xplore Digital Library) is what I meant but the persistent reader will figure this out. Best regards.